# Keeping track of selected list item in a master page

Tags: asp.net, javascript

As per the functionality of the headers in stackoverflow (Questions, Tags, Users, Badges, ...), I would like to keep track of which list item a user has selected in an ASP.NET MVC view so I can apply a different style or image.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Thanks Pawel. Upon investigation I see that you are correct. Do you have any idea how I would keep track of which item I selected if I did not want to render a new view?

Answer (score 0):

If you look closely at Stack Overflow you will notice that each of these links points to a different controller, which most likely (I'm guessing) renders a different view just reusing some UI elements through a common master page. So there's no need to 'remember' anything, how the returned page looks like is defined in a view for that page.